# Cannot log in using IE 8?

Tags: bug, status-declined

Using IE8, I don't see the login link at the top to enable me to log in, but with Chrome and Firefox I can. Anyone else have this problem and a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for bringing this up. Per [our official supported browsers wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/262550), we do not support IE8. Therefore, I recommend that you upgrade your browser (it's likely that you have by now, 2+ years later) to ensure an optimal experience on our sites.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 generates [a fair number of complaints on the mother meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=IE8&submit=search), but I don't see one exactly like this. The closest I've got is [Autologin working sporadically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109618/2509.).

Has this started recently after it was working for a while? The team does tinker with the code and this could be a regression if it is new.

Comment: aha... yes! I didn't realize I was being auto-logged in because my username isn't shown at the top as with Chrome and firefox - it's just blank for IE8 so I can't click on it.

Comment: It's working now.